# Course of actions to fix small (I think) rotten floor beside shower tub

Tags: bathroom, repair, subfloor, water-damage

Just moved in new (old) house, one tile beside shower tub in master bath were bouncing, I see cracks in the grout around, tile itself is pretty intact.  Wondering best course of actions to fix those this in a good way.

What I've done so far:

1. Took out the the bouncing tile, and one beside that.
2. Took out and cleaned all loose subfloor, motar, backer board, plywood, even some like 4in into the wall on the left side.
3. Blowed for a few days, and checked moisture level around inside and outside (using meter), everything seems to dried out.
4. Turn on shower for 30 mins with door closes, just to make sure the leaking is not from inside, it looks good.
5. Did a test using screwer driver, make sure all the area around the open area are solid.

My plan for next steps are:

1. Using [Bondo restorer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3M-8-fl-oz-Rotted-Wood-Restorer-20131/206680616?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D24-024_013_INT_STAIN_CL-NA-Multi-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FY21_Interior_PLALIA&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D24-024_013_INT_STAIN_CL-NA-Multi-NA-PLALIA-NA-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-FY21_Interior_PLALIA-71700000075826925-58700006496910117-92700058691144896&gclid=CjwKCAjwhdWkBhBZEiwA1ibLmMnaBz7ttui0Eyr0IAvtAcn2vf5h4bpoXOKVvDMi1DuwRg-1u5vFIRoCDtIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to harden the rotten area and joint
2. sister two studs on the rotten joint, it seems like that's the only joint impacted.
3. patch some [wood filler](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Bondo-12-Ounce-Gold-Paintable-Wood-Filler-30081/206680651) the fill the gaps (uneven adjacent)
4. cut 3/4 plywood board to cover this area, 4 inches into the wall,
5. Screw and thinset-motar cement backer board on top of drywall
6. fill the gap with some [SimplePrepFloor patch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-SimplePrep-1-Gal-Pre-Mixed-Floor-Patch-FP1/100678058)
7. thinset motar two spare tiles
8. grout the gaps
9. caulk edges between tile and base board/shower tub

I have some doubts hopefully I can get some help,

1. Do i need to worry about the gap/uneven part between the new plywood/backer board and subfloor in the wall? (I won't be able to patch/wood fill those areas unless I cut out the wall, it's doable though as this is not load bearing wall, and adjacent room is just the closet)
2. Do I need take out more tiles or even the shower tub? (I checked the wood below those areas seems to be solid.
3. Am I better off find some professional to do this?

[image: after take out tile]

[image]

Comment: I think you'll need to support the edge of the tub where the floor rotted out, and I'm not clear that your proposed solution as described addresses that. The left side from about two inches past the joist on the right appears to be completely unsupported, and you didn't mention your floor patch extending under the tub.

Comment: That looks like a drywall ceiling below.  I'd recommend opening that up to do the additional work that Ecnerwal is inferring will be necessary.  You're gonna have to paint anyway, I can't imagine that there aren't any water spots on the ceiling based on what I see on the top side.

Comment: thank you both @Ecnerwal and Huesmann,  this is second floor,  however I check underneath are cabinets in the laundry room,  a little bit beyond what I can handle myself.  Just called the professionals.  

I would like to mark both of your comment to answers,  not sure how to do that for comments.